Employment Contract Update - What happens if I do not sign?
I have worked at a Company (London) for 11 years - it is now in a cash critical position and potentially will become insolvent / will be sold.
When I joined, my contract was basic and about 2 paragraphs long! In 2021 a HR Manager joined (new position) and created a new Employee Handbook - within this extensive 20 page handbook there are clauses which refer to lay offs and shortage of work. Ie “I agree the company can lay me off” (no mention of severance pay) it is pretty bleak and states “this section forms part of your legal contract”. It was stored for reference and I cannot see any log of it being circulated or a request for signature.
Last week, a new HR manager circulated an updated version (3 years later) requesting all to sign and approve. The updates were small and insignificant. My fear is that they are about to make lay offs or try to cut hours and realise they didn’t have employees signatures. Whilst I am reluctant to sign, I am aware by not doing so and coming to work, I am affirming. I wonder if I can be dismissed if I have not signed by the deadline?
The HR manager is not impartial and sadly cannot be trusted with confidential conversations. The timing of the circulation of the updated handbook which now needs signature really stinks! I cannot see how we have money for redundancies, but after nearly 11 years the thought of being laid off with (zero?) payout is scary.
Any thoughts or experiences appreciated.

Close voters: this falls under the "something a reasonably competent HR person should know and can comment on without knowing specifics" exception to the "no legal advice" general rule.

Note, if a company can’t pay you redundancy due to insolvency, you can claim it from the government.
https://www.gov.uk/your-rights-if-your-employer-is-insolvent

@Darren - Note: the government only pays redundancy up to whatever value that the law states you are entitled to.  It is possible that you have much better redundancy benefit from your employer as part of your contract.  Should the employer be unable to meet that amount, the government does not give you what your contract entitled you to.  I suspect from the original question that this will not be the case here, but as someone who was told during an agreement with an employer who was making me redundant but not paying - "The government will pay all redundancy due", I was bitterly disappointed.

You can't sign away the protections you have in employment law.

Thank you all. I cannot see how the company is going to be able to pay any redundancy, hence I am fearing lay offs are a possibility. I cannot see any mention of severance in my contract. Could I potentially be laid off without any payment at all?? Thanks in advance

As you are in the UK and have more than two years service, there are three options:

You agree to the new terms and conditions.
You do not agree to the new terms and conditions, and your employer continues to employ you under the old terms and conditions.
You do not agree to the new terms and conditions. Your employer deems that it is essential to the business for employees to be employed under the new T&Cs and makes you redundant (emphasis deliberate). That's something they're allowed to do, but they would have to go through the full legal redundancy procedure, including all the protections that gives you as an employee. Crucially, they cannot fairly dismiss you directly.


Thank you, the section re layoffs and shortage of work is not new (it was in the old version from 3 years ago), but that version was not requested to be signed. So I could be made redundant but not dismissed? Thanks in advance

Yes; just repeatedly state that you never agreed to the change from 3 years ago.

Maybe send an email to HR clearly stating that you do not agree to the new stuff, for paper record.

@stopkillinggames.com And while it's implied, be sure that you have a paper copy of that email, the email chain, and any replies outside of the company's control.

The employer could dismiss you for refusing to sign the new contract, but - depending on the circumstances - you may be able to claim compensation for unfair dismissal

As to option 3, if they were looking for layoffs they would probably choose some sucker who signed the new T&C rather than someone who knows their rights.  Assuming the management is rational, which of course is a big if.

Of course, if the company is going insolvent then redundancies are pretty easy to prove and it's possible you're putting a target on your back.  If your original contract had nothing above statutory rights then it's not something you can sign away in any case.

@throx  Might be better to get made redundant now (for being a trouble-maker), while the company is still solvent, than to be laid-off next month, when they have no money at all.

@MikeB it looks like you can still get statutory redundancy pay (and the OP was never going to get more than that legal minimum).  It looks like this is done through a government body rather than through the administrators of the company's assets
